# Why use notations like $f(x)$ while explaining mathematical proofs or equations etc

Tags: education

If there is a variable "$x$" , and another is "$y$", and let's say 
I know the relation between them as

$$x= y+1$$

Now, I want to use them in the explanation of some mathematical theory/proof/equation etc. Why a different notation called $f(x)$ ( function of $x$ ) is used to represent $y$ ? Why can't y itself be used ? Cannot i just remember that "$y$" has some relation with "$x$" .  Is their some other importance also, other than representing a relation of "$y$" with "$x$", when some term like $f(x)$ is used ?

Comment: Early on, the notion of 'functions' are introduced in much more detail and rigor than the notion of 'dependent variables'. Thus, there is a tendency to phrase things in terms of functions rather than in terms of dependent variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're essentially the same thing, except for a couple of points.  Writing y = x - 1 obfuscates the relationship between y and x.  Does y depend on x or is y a constant?  Is x a constant or is it a variable?  It's not clear just by writing y = x - 1 what exactly you mean.  On the other hand, inserting the variable makes it transparent what's going on.  Now you might just be tempted to say "assume y is always considered a function of x and suppress variable notation".  Fine.  What about y = xz - 2z + x - 1?  Does y depend on x and z?  Does z depend on any other parameter?  It quickly becomes confusing what you mean.

I suppose nothing is stopping you from writing y(x) = x - 1 and inserting the dependency.  It's done in some contexts.  But then you're just using a different letter for f, which doesn't seem much different.  Also, f is a stand in for "function", I'd guess.

Comment: In y = xz - 2z + x - 1 , we can say y = f(x,z) ?? ie. value of y depends upon both, x as well as z ?

Comment: If y depends on x and z, sure.  But maybe y doesn't depend on either.  Or only one.  Or maybe z depends on x too so we have f(x, z(x)).  The point is having this notation helps clarify what exactly is intended.